# When should I use redux with React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was getting started with React Navigation. Though its really amazing library but the documentation still needs some work.

I have following scenarios which I need to take care of:-

1. Pushing a new screen based on conditions.
2. Pushing screen to current StackNavigator.
3. Going back to a screen based on few conditions.
4. Clearing the route stack on logout.

From what I understand all these can clearly be achieved without using redux.

What are the benefits of using redux with React Navigation? Are there any specific things which can be achieved only if I used redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redux is used for managing the data of your app and does not have much to do with React Navigation. You can do everything you listed without redux.

React Navigation provides a framework for navigating from screen to screen and passing some data within those screens.

redux will give you a framework for managing your data (state) through dispatching actions, and responding to those actions as they complete.

You can, of course, combine them so that redux is managing changes to your state, and then you can act on those state changes to trigger navigation events.